# Do my articles published in local newspapers count as publications?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, application

I'm applying to Columbia's journalism school and it asked me if I have any publications. Since I worked as a reporter before for the local newspaper, and I did write a few headline stories, I thought this might help my journalism application. But since they're nor academic, I'm not sure if I should put down my news articles as "publications."

Comment: Rule of thumb: is it relevant for your application? put it in. Is it irrelevant? leave it out.

Answer (score 75):

It's not uncommon to have subheadings for different kinds of publications. "Peer-reviewed journal articles", "Proceedings", "Monographs" and so on. For a journalism program, "Newspaper articles" seems like a completely appropriate subheading.

Comment: Or "popular press"  -- this kind of publication is highly prized in some circles, it shows the author's abilities to make complex ideas clear and relevant for a broader audience of non-specialists.

Comment: This seems particularly relevant given that the OP is applying to journalism school.

Answer (score 13):

If that's a school which teaches journalism, then **definitely**, but like @rturnbull suggests, list them separately from anything else, since they're not academic publications *about* journalism.

If it's a graduate program for the study of journalism, then **possibly, but only to a minor extent** - and still it's the same practical advice: List them separately from anything else.